# Product symbol c on the lower suffix

Tags: symbols, subscripts

Sorry, this may be very easy question but I didn't get. When I use product symbol, I want to write c(as a cardinal product) in the lower suffix. I am using following command.

```
\documentclass{12 pt}{article}

\begin{document}

$\prod_{i = 1}^{n}_{c} A_{i}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure want exactkly you like to get but you can inlcude the `_c` part inside the braces of `n`:

```
\prod_{i = 1}^{n_c} A_{i}
```

which will give

[image]

Pleas note that the first argument of `\documentclass` is optional and for that needy square brackets, and the font size option is without a space, i.e. `12pt` instead of `12 pt` …

Comment: Thank you very much Tobi. Actually, I need c in the lower suffix of product. Like \prod_{c}, where c represent the symbol of cardinal product.

Comment: Then it's `\mathop{\prod_c}\limits_{i=1}^n`

Comment: @kahen: Why don’t you extend your comment and write an answer (e.g. explaining why the `\mathop` is necessary …)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what you want the "c" to be a suffix of? Would either

```
${\prod_{i = 1}^{n}}_{c} A_{i}$
```

or

```
${\prod_c}^n_{i = 1} A_{i}$
```

suffice?

Also, your first line of code should be: `\documentclass[12 pt]{article}`.